# Неправильный хэш ключ при авторизации Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

Собственно, суть проблемы такова. Есть Android приложение. В нём реализован функционал постинга. Но для получения разрешения необходима авторизация. Так вот проблема кроется именно здесь. Если на девайсе нет приложения Facebook, то для авторизации открывается WebView и авторизация проходит в нём успешно. А если приложение Facebook на девайсе присутствует, то авторизация не проходит ив LogCat ввыдаётся сообщение о неправильном хэш ключе. Ключ в моём профиле и тот, который показывается отличается лишь тем, что нет в конце знака = и вместо / написан _ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, нужно читать внимательнее документацию. Я перепутал hash ключи для примеров в профиле разработчика и hash в профиле приложения.

Answer (score 0):

у меня в Developer консоли в FB указаны ключи, оканчивающиеся на знак '='.
попробуй разместить оба варианта, все-таки ключей прописать довольно много можно.

Comment: Нет, не получается. Я пробовал добавлять такие ключи, но они не воспринимаются Facebook, как ключи. Вставляю, а после сохранения их там нет. Такие варианты я уже пробовал. Я гуглил эту проблему. Мне хотелось бы найти ответ, в какой функции Facebook SDK происходит эта генерация и почему она отличается от той, которая происходит при WebView.